# Rank Function in MySQL by LeetCode #178

Tags: mysql

leetcode #178 RankScores.

I found some information about `Rank Function` in `MySQL`, and then I write the below code:

```
SELECT Score, 
CASE  
  WHEN @prevRank = Score Then @Rank 
  WHEN @prevRank:= Score Then @Rank := @Rank +1 
END AS rank 
FROM Scores s, (SELECT @Rank:=0,@prevRank :=NULL) r 
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

but I don't know what's the meaning of `@prevRank:= Score`.

Answer (score 0):

If @prevRank = Score, case will enter first branch if @prevRank equal Score
Else
@prevRank := Score will put score into @prevRank variable AND add @rank + 1, in the same time.